# Weird action when converting Java to Scala code. Returning a new object in function

Tags: scala

I'm converting some old Java code to Scala.  I have this.

```
    class XYCustomRenderer(dataMax: Double, dataMin: Double) extends XYShapeRenderer with BaseChart {

    override def getItemPaint(series: Int, item: Int): Paint = {

        val seriesCollection: TimeSeriesCollection = getPlot.getDataset(OUNCES_CHART).asInstanceOf[ TimeSeriesCollection ]

        val ounce = seriesCollection.getYValue(series, item)

        if ( ounce >= dataMax || ounce <= dataMin ) {
            new Color(255, 161, 15, 200)
        }

        new Color(242, 29, 5, 150)

    }
}
```

This is a straight conversion pretty much.

I'm having issues getting the color to return right.

If I write it as shown it always returns the bottom color.

If I write it like this(with the return).

```
if ( ounce >= dataMax || ounce <= dataMin ) {
            return new Color(255, 161, 15, 200)
        }

        new Color(242, 29, 5, 150)
```

It always returns the color in the if block.  That doesn't make any sense to me.  Is scala behaving a certain way that I'm not sure.

I'm just trying to return two different colors based on logic.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If it always return the color in the if statement, with the return statement, then the condition is always true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if` is an expression in Scala. And the last expression in a method gets implicitly returned. So you either have to write this (notice the `else` clause):

```
if ( ounce >= dataMax || ounce <= dataMin )
  new Color(255, 161, 15, 200)
else
  new Color(242, 29, 5, 150)
```

or the version with an explicit `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to log (or use a debugger) to see the actual values of ounce, dataMax, and dataMin?

What is the type returned by seriesCollection.getYValue(series, item)?

Comment: Well the dataMin and Max are right.  What's happening is if I don't put a return on new Color it doesn't work.  I have to put a return for both of them.  I was just wondering why that was?

Comment: Well, agilesteel's answer seems clear to me ;-) If you need more, tell us!